# Hbase rest api and basic authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, hbase

I'd like to setup hbase rest server to use basic authentication but all the documentations I find are about kerberos.

Does anybody know how to do so? Is it even possible?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by 'basic authentication' or where did you see that ?  You mean without authentication ?

Comment: Hi sel-fish, I mean basic authentication using username and password provided in the URL e.g. http://myuser:mypassword@hbaserestsrv.com. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication for further information.

Comment: i mean where did you see that hbase rest server can provide so called 'basic authentication' :) I don't think that is possible, maybe you are enlightened by mysql/memcached/redis,  but it seems only kerberos is available http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/security.html

Comment: That is why I asked "Is it even possible?". But since there must be a servlet on the hbase rest server it might be possible somehow. So I ask ;)